# Moving section navigation block without breaking mobile navigation

Tags: magento-2.1, css, xml

So I have this XML file to move the navigation:

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

On Desktop, I need some styling to try and keep it between the logo and the search bar so I have added this CSS inside of a `_navigation_extend.less` file:

```
.nav-sections {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 52%;
    float: left;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

This fixes my issue on desktop mode but completely breaks mobile navigation. How can I fix this on desktop mode and keep the current style for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some CSS being applied in the LESS file `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less` and it shows how to apply CSS for the Desktop breakpoints. My new file looks like this:

```
// DESKTOP
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .nav-sections {
        background-color: transparent;
        position: relative;
        top: -12px;
        left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        width: 52%;
        float: left;
    }
    .navigation {
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: 400;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}
```

So all I really did was copy that breakpoint logic and put my CSS inside. Awesome!